# Oracle DML Error Logging field type

Tags: database, oracle, logging, dml

I wanna ask about the DML Error Logging in Oracle
I have an original table with this structure

```
table_test(
ID Int PK,
test_time date
)
```

I also create an error logging table for this
ERR$_table_test

As I know, the field '`ID'` and '`test_time'` in `ERR$_table_test` is `VARCHAR(4000)`

Let me take an example

```
1. Insert into table_test values (1,to_date('18/08/2015 15:00:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

==> successful, 1 row inserted

```
2. Insert into table_test values (1,to_date('18/08/2015 15:00:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

==> 0 row inserted in table_test, 1 row in ERR$_table_test with this error: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

```
3. select * from ERR$_table_test
```

1 record found: but the field test_time is '18/08/2015' with no time <== I want full time stamp for this field

After that, I try to alter table ERR$_table_test

```
alter table ERR$_table_test modify test_time date
```

I redo exactly above example

This time I got full time stamp for test_time in ERR$_table_test

But, then I try

```
Insert into table_test values (2,to_date('abc xyz' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

==> An SQL error occurs when insert wrong type in ERR$_table_test

This is the thing I concerned about

1. Could I get full time stamp in ERR$_table_test without changing it's column type ?
2. If I have to change the column type into DATE, could I still receive the error log for the second case, when the format of time is wrong ?

Thank you for any support,

Comment: have you tried running `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');` in the session prior to doing the insert?

Answer (score 2):

If it can evaluate the date then it converts it back to a string to put into the `varchar2(4000)` column using your session settings. As it's a date field you can control that by setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT prior to executing the insert:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Insert into table_test values (1,to_date('18/08/2015 15:00:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) log errors into err$_table_test;

Insert into table_test values (1,to_date('18/08/2015 15:00:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) log errors into err$_table_test;

Insert into table_test values (2,to_date('abc xyz' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) log errors into err$_table_test;

column id format a10
column test_time format a20
select ora_err_number$, id, test_time from ERR$_table_test;

                        ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ ID         TEST_TIME          
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------
                                      1 1          2015-08-18 15:00:00 
                                   1858 2          abc xyz
```

Which isn't ideal, particularly if you might be inserting from multiple clients, whose settings you can't control.

But as [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#CJAHJIBE) notes, if you use a date datatype in your error logging table rather than the recommended (and default, if created through `DBMS_ERRLOG`) `varchar2(4000)`, a failure to convert - as with your `abc xyz` value - will cause the whole statement to fail:

> Because type conversion errors are one type of error that might occur, the data types of the optional columns in the error logging table must be types that can capture any value without data loss or conversion errors. (If the optional log columns were of the same types as the DML table columns, capturing the problematic data into the log could suffer the same data conversion problem that caused the error.) The database makes a best effort to log a meaningful value for data that causes conversion errors. If a value cannot be derived, NULL is logged for the column. An error on insertion into the error logging table causes the statement to terminate.

So to answer your second question, no; if you change the error log data type to DATE then you won't get errors logged for invalid date/time formats, the statement will just terminate.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it works, but is there any option besides changing nls_date_format for current session, because my SQL statement will be run automatically in a script with others so I'm afraid that this change could affect the others

Comment: @mrzenky - you shouldn't have anything in your script that relies on NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Which is why this isn't ideal, since it's adding that reliance; but as Oracle is doing an implicit conversion I don't see any other way around it. You could, I suppose, capture and reset the original setting; but that doesn't really make sense unless you only have a few statements with error logging enabled.